# mongo group and sort by largest groups

Tags: mongodb

Say I have the following documents structure where I keep employees, their respective location, and company they work for:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "city": "milan",
    "company": "apple"
},
{
    "name": "nicole",
    "city": "rome",
    "company": "microsoft"
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve, ideally within one request, is to give me top `n` groups individually across city and company. I want to have top `n` cities and top `n` companies they work for.

For exmaple:

```
[
    {
        "milan": 23,
        "rome": 21,
        "new york": 18,
        "berlin": 10
    },
    {
        "facebook": 10,
        "apple": 8,
        "amazon": 8,
        "google": 2
    }
]
```

What I can do is simple aggregation pipeline with `$sum` but that scans the whole collection and does not give me top (most popular) results.

Comment: Perhaps `$unionWith` or `$facet`?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tVNCSeifmIt for a starter

Comment: or https://mongoplayground.net/p/9y3lOAu-cy7 not sure if best

Comment: @cmgchess Both solutions work perfectly fine in my case. If you can post here as an answer for anyone who's looking for the same thing, I can upvote and close.

Comment: @Pono sure. i posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$facet` in this case as mentioned in the comment by [@user20042973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20042973/user20042973)
i used the `k` and `v` format so that I can use `$arrayToObject` on a later stage to convert it to an object

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      cities: [
        { $group: { _id: "$city", v: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { v: -1 } },
        { $limit: n },
        { $project: { k: "$_id", v: "$v", _id: 0 } }
      ],
      companies: [
        { $group: { _id: "$company", v: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { v: -1 } },
        { $limit: n },
        { $project: { k: "$_id", v: "$v", _id: 0 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { converted: [ { $arrayToObject: "$cities" }, { $arrayToObject: "$companies" } ] } },
  { $unwind: "$converted" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$converted" } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9y3lOAu-cy7)

Comment: when `city` or `company` is actually an `objectId` the `$arrayToObject` fails with because it expects a string. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @Pono convert to string using `$toString`? https://mongoplayground.net/p/sPHG-WNKTHC

Comment: Thank you for this. I much appreciate your fully-working examples with playgrounds.

Comment: @Pono yeah its a nice tool to try out stuff. also there is a dropdown on top where you can see the output in intermediate stages